# How do I prevent keyboard events in a WPF dialog box from bleeding through to the MFC application which invoked it?

Tags: wpf, mfc, key-bindings, keyevent

We have a legacy MFC application which we are extending with new WPF views and dialog boxes. I am trying to implement F1 help in a WPF dialog box that gets invoked from the MFC main window.

Initially I added a `KeyBinding` to the WPF dialog for F1, and had it fire a command that runs `HtmlHelp`; something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <command:CommandReference x:Key="ShowF1Help" Command="{Binding ShowHelpCommand}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding x:Name="ShowHelp" Gesture="F1" Command="{StaticResource ShowF1Help}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

This brought up Help, but unfortunately the keyboard event was *also* picked up by the MFC window; even though the WPF dialog was modally displayed on top of it, the MFC window still received F1 and so it launched `HtmlHelp` a second time, showing its own topic.

I searched for a way to mark the event as handled within the `XAML/KeyBinding` element but had no luck. So I tried to brute-force it and replaced that with a `KeyDown` handler in the code-behind, marking the event as handled, like this:

```
private void WindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F1)
    {
        MyDialogVM.ShowContextSensitiveHelp();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This didn't work; the event still winds up getting handled by the MFC window. I also tried `PreviewKeyDown` --same results.

I have a feeling that I'm overlooking something obvious, but it sure looks like marking a WPF event as handled only affects WPF code, and the MFC message pump has no knowledge that the managed code has seen or handled a given keyboard event.

Is there a way to prevent keyboard events that are handled in a WPF dialog box from also being seen by the MFC application that invoked the dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of questions: 1) is the owner of the WPF dialog the MFC window? If you didn't do anything explicitly, it isn't by default. 2) is the main window disabled when the wpf dialog is up? If it isn't, probably because of issue 1.

You need something like:

```
var hlpr = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper( xaml_window );
hlpr.Owner = mfc_window_handle;
```

Comment: Hi Joel, yes we are explicitly setting the MFC window as the owner of the WPF dialog, and the WPF dialog is behaving modally; you cannot click and give focus to the underlying MFC dialog.

Comment: Rats, probably as issue with MFC and WPF sharing the message pump. You may have to apply a msg filter on the MFC side to ignore key presses while the WPF dialog is up.

Comment: Yeah that is my suspicion as well. Your suggestion of filtering keyboard events on the unmanaged side is exactly what I've been considering as a last resort, but I was *seriously* hoping to avoid going that route. I assume this is a rare enough situation that Microsoft didn't get all the kinks worked out. Anyway, thanks again.